# Trend line constants in VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm new to VB but it seems this should be simple. I'm trying to get the constants for a linear trend line in my VB project.

```
    Dim WStemp1 As WorksheetFunction
    Dim WStemp2 As WorksheetFunction

    X1_home = WStemp1.Index(WStemp2.LinEst(y_values, x_values), 1, 1)
    C1_home = WStemp1.Index(WStemp2.LinEst(y_values, x_values), 1, 2)
```

This code works fine in vba, but I get the following error

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myApp.exe
    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show how you instantiate `WStemp1` and `WStemp2`

Comment: that is it, I don't initiate them. how would you suggest doing this?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction` is a property of an Excel Application object - do you have a reference to Excel in your project?  Typically you'd use something like `xlApp.WorksheetFunction` where `xlApp` is your Excel application instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must instatiate your WorksheetFunction objects from the Excel application. For example:

```
Dim App As New Excel.Application
Dim ExcelFunc As Excel.WorksheetFunction = App.WorksheetFunction

'Use the excel function
Dim avg As Double 
avg = ExcelFunc.Average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

'release objects and terminate Excel application
ExcelFunc = Nothing
App.Quit()
App = Nothing
```

Cheers